# flutter Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle' java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4zLG.png)
I get this error as above when running "flutter build appbundle"

build.gradle->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCXAP.png)

I tried cleaning the project and double checked keystore file directory

Comment: Do not post code as images. Add code to the question as a code snippet.